# How to download pages from a website having specific string in the end of url with wget?

Tags: wget

I am looking to download a website for offline viewing. So I have no need of images. All I need is the content in that page.
wget does the thing. wget downloads all the data from a website if given directly when I use -r as an argument.
I just want to download content of all the links ending with some alphabet like "x" OR "p" in the end of url of the website I am downloading

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wget -A '*[xp]' ...
```

From [Types of Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html#Types-of-Files):

> The argument to ‘--accept’ option is a list of file suffixes or patterns that Wget will download during recursive retrieval. A suffix is the ending part of a file, and consists of “normal” letters, e.g. ‘gif’ or ‘.jpg’. A matching pattern contains shell-like wildcards, e.g. ‘books*’ or ‘zelazny*196[0-9]*’.
>
> So, specifying ‘wget -A gif,jpg’ will make Wget download only the files ending with ‘gif’ or ‘jpg’, i.e. gifs and jpegs. On the other hand, ‘wget -A "zelazny*196[0-9]*"’ will download only files beginning with ‘zelazny’ and containing numbers from 1960 to 1969 anywhere within. Look up the manual of your shell for a description of how pattern matching works.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -O yourfile.zip http://www.site.com/?id=34ee
```

or

```
wget -O customFileName http://www.x.com/y/z
mv id=34ee yourfile.zip
```